# SBS 2008, installing updates 3 of 5, for 6 hours?

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop

I've got a Small Business Server 2008, which I sent to restart, via Windows Update, at about 3pm GMT, it's now 8:30pm and it is still showing Installing updates 3 of 5.

I think that it may have stalled or is simply stuck, I can connect the machine via LogMeIn, however not by any other means, I can see the install screen.

Is there anyway I can force it to restart, or check that it really is still updating?

Comment: I assume you don't have physical access to the server?

Comment: No I'm afraid not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that LogMeIn does have the ability to restart the host machine! - So I used that to force it to reboot :-)